# Footer overlapping content

Tags: css, xhtml, footer, sticky-footer

Thanks for you're help.

You can view this [online](http://www.underweardelivery.com)

The problem is my footer.  It won't seem to stay below the content.  I attempted to use [Matthew James Taylor's method](http://matthewjamestaylor.com/blog/keeping-footers-at-the-bottom-of-the-page) which is not working for me.  I need the footer to stay below the content when the content fills the page, and stay at the bottom of the window when the content does not fill the page (sticky footer).  I'm seeking a non-JS solution.

Thanks again.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

put an empty div element at the end of `.container`  element with clear:both; like this

```
<div style="clear:both;"></div>
```

And remove height from `#tabs`  element. you have set it as `height: 500px;`

Comment: @Shota inside the end of the container or right after the container?

Comment: inside the container and remove the height from `#tabs` element.

Comment: @Shota I've placed the clearing DIV, but the #tabs height is being written by a javascript.  How do I remove that, and will it have a negative affect on the tabs?

Comment: I've removed height with firebug and footer got to it's place. try it.

Comment: @Shota Wow, yeah.  But, I have no idea how to remove the height in the JS file.  I'll update my post with the code.  If you have any idea, please let me know.

Comment: @Shota, Wait, I think the height is on the .content.

Comment: as I see the height is set in m.css file on line 106

Comment: @Shota Yeah, it was the .contents DIV.  Thanks a lot for your help!